# Change Map type in Google MAP v3 dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need to change the map type of google Map v3 from click on button outside of map. How can I do that, possibly without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just call setMapTypeId on the map object:

```
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
```

Comment: How do we set the map dynamically in jetpack compose ?